# sql Server remove value after point

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I Have folowing Sql query in which i am using round function but it dont removes the demimal points after point.

Here is Query

```
SELECT     animal_code, ROUND(SUM(calve_milk + evening + morning) / 31, 0) AS Expr1
FROM         Status
WHERE     (animal_code = 147) AND (m_date BETWEEN '1/1/2012' AND '1/31/2012')
GROUP BY animal_code
```

This Query Results

```
10.00000
```

And I want to get only 10 from this query.How can i do this in sql server 2005

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `CAST` around your `ROUND`.

`CAST(ROUND(SUM(calve_milk + evening + morning) / 31, 0) AS INT)`

Answer (score 0):

Use this sql query:

```
SELECT     animal_code, CAST(ROUND(SUM(calve_milk + evening + morning) / 31, 0) as BIGINT) AS Expr1
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the rounded result to an integer.

For example:

```
SELECT CONVERT(Int, ROUND(1234.1234, 0))
```